# Get column value for specific post

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the value of the 'relate' column in my DB for the specific post.

This is what I've tried so far...

submit_post.php ($var->get_relateCount)

```
// Construct
public function __construct($content, $emotion)
{
    $this->content = $content;
    $this->emotion = $emotion;
    $this->post = 
        "<div id=\'post\'>
            <div id=\'postContent\'>
                <p><b>I\'m $this->emotion because</b> $this->content<span class=\'emot\'id=\'$this->emotion\'></span></p>
            </div>
            <div id=\'postInfo\'>
                <span class=\'postRelate\' title=\'Click to relate +1\'><p><b>relate</b> (**<?php $var->get_relateCount($conn,'$this->content') ?>**)</p></span>
                <span class=\'postSubmitted\'><p>submitted 2 minutes ago</p></span>
            </div>
        </div>";     
}
```

get_post.php

```
// Get relate count
public function get_relateCount($conn,$content)
{
    // SQL INSERT command
    $sql = 
    "
    SELECT relate FROM userPost
    WHERE content = '$content'
    ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["relate"];
            echo "test";
        }
    } else {
        echo "X";
    }
}
```

get_post.php echo's all the posts (stored as div's in the database) onto the feed.

So to be clear: I'm looking to get the the count of the 'relate' column for the specific post which is why in my query I'm specifying it to **WHERE content = '$content'**.

Will make the question clearer if it's too difficult to understand what I'm looking for. Currently it's echoing the PHP code itself.

Comment: Why escaping single quotes when your string is delimited by double quotes?

Comment: I get a fatal error if not. A problem I'm currently experiencing is when a user posts anything with quotes it'll produce an error (eg. "I'm okay"). However, that's a problem for another time.